# How to change datatype to timestamp using unix_timestamp and from_unixtime Hive functions

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CAST(arrival_time as TIMESTAMP),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) as arr_time,
CAST(arrival_time as TIMESTAMP) as arrival_time
```

Output:

```
arr time                         arrival_time
2020-06-15 05:20:24             2020-06-15T05:20:24.000+0000
2020-06-15 05:20:24             2020-06-15T05:20:24.000+0000
2020-06-15 05:20:24             2020-06-15T05:20:24.000+0000
2020-06-15 05:20:24             2020-06-15T05:20:24.000+0000
```

Converting directly into timestamp gives me `2020-06-15T05:20:24.000+0000`
but I am looking for `2020-06-15 05:20:24` which I am getting using **unix_timestamp and from_unixtime Hive functions** but the problem is that datatype remains as a string only, I want datatype as a timestamp.

How we can create `2020-06-15 05:20:24` as a timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_timestamp`.

```
select to_timestamp(arrival_time) from table
```